# Meteor DDP call between containers on same host

Tags: meteor, docker, ddp

This Meteor App server code tries to use the method of another Meteor worker. both the app and the worker are in a separate docker containers on the same server EC2. The worker is running on port 9000.
When the App fires a method `appCallingWorker`, I expected to see the worker container logs out the string 'worker called from App' but all `docker logs containerID` gives is many lines looking like this:
`stream error Network error: ws://localhost:9000/websocket: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000`

How can I use the methods of the worker from the App? thx

```
//App/server/main.js
let workerConn = DDP.connect('http://localhost:9000');
Meteor.methods({
 'appCallingWorker': () => {
   workerConn.call('workerMethod');
  }
});

//Worker/server/main.js
Meteor.methods({
  'workerMethod': function () {
    console.log('worker called from App');
  }
})
```

**edit**
The EC2 is a Container Instance in AWS ECS. and the containerDefinitions.portMapings.containerPort and hostPort are both set to 9000.
**edit 2**
iptables -L -n on the docker host shows the ip of the container listening on 9000, I replaced localhost in the code with said ip and now it works. But Said ip can change if host reboot or container restarts... another problem to find a solution for.

Comment: The connection was refused, meaning that there is nothing listening on localhost:9000. If your apps are in separate docker containers, do they have their own ip's, and should you be trying to connect to that?

Comment: @Mikkel I answered you good observation in an edit to my post. thx for your input. If my process is not complete, please provide some more info.

Comment: All you did was replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 - this is not a valid network address,

Comment: @Mikkel I see. So the `iptables -L -n` showed me the ip for 9000, replaced localhost with the that ip and it works. but that number can change any time the EC2 reboots or the container restarts, then how can I make this 'auto discover'? thx

Comment: You can use Route53 to lock in a fixed IP address, or even use a dynamic one with a name (such as myserver.mydomain.com) , which you put in your code

Comment: @Mikkel internal traffic between the Containers should not need to traverse the Route53 'my 2c'. your thoughts?

Comment: See @rkstar's answer - that is what I was trying to tell you, use the public IP address, and use route53 to give it a dns entry so that you don't need to hard wire an ipaddress

Answer (score 0):

i had this same problem trying to communicate between docker containers.  you're going to have to use the external ip:port address of the server your containers are on.

Comment: AWS autoscale or manual recreating the EC2 in the ECS cluster will void the ip, then what?

Comment: can you use a domain name?  `service.myapp.com:9000` or something?

Comment: What about back end workers which do not have a domain name?, Would using a domain name make local traffic between the Containers traverse the internet?

Comment: @FredJ. the request will have to go out before coming back in, but it should only be 1 hop because the first name server it hits will direct the request back to the same ip.  in fact, you could edit the `/etc/hosts` file on the machine to point any domain name directly to the ip you want in effect fooling the docker container into thinking it's going outside.